# How to maintain data in pojo class for session scope spring mvc 3.0.3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have searched the forum form my query but could not find a answer.
I am new to spring mvc so i am little bit confused it will be great if some one helps me out,

I have a spring mvc application, i get some data from request parameter, i have to maintain that data through out the session. how could i achieve this using Spring 3.0.3.

I had some idea in mind to implement this

1> create a pojo with session scope
2> Then in controller autowire the pojo and populate the pojo.
3> Since it is in session scope the value populated should be available throughout the session

Please let me know if i am on the right track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea you said is one way to work with session scoped beans. You can define your session scoped POJO:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class YourSessionBean{
...
}
```

and then you can inject it in your Controller classes:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
     @Autowired
     private YourSessionBean yourSessionBean;
     ...
}
```

You can also use [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib) to store your POJO into session:

```
public class YourObject {
...
}
```

and you can use `@SessionAttributes` annotation in your controller to put an instance of `YourObject` into session:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("yourObj")
public class YourController {
     ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/url")  
    public ModelAndView process(...) {  
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();  
    modelAndView.addObject("yourObj", new YourObject());  // this will put YourObj into session

    return modelAndView;  
}  
}
```

But, while using `@SessionAttributes`, you should consider below block of statements (copied from [@SessionAttributes Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html)):

> NOTE: Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond
>   to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored
>   in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the
>   handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore,
>   use this facility for such conversational attributes which are
>   supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of
>   a specific handler's conversation.
>
> For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object,
>   use the traditional session.setAttribute method instead.

You can also use `HttpSession` as a method argument for your `@RequestMapping` handler methods and then add your POJO class to the session:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
     ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/url")  
    public ModelAndView process(HttpSession session,...) {  
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();  
    session.setAttribute("yourObj", yourObj);
    ...  
    return modelAndView;  
}  
}
```